# I'm at lost with my error regarding c# code (asp.net) web application

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
LinkButton btnCerFormsMon_Print = (LinkButton)sender;

Repeater Item = (Repeater)btnCerFormsMon_Print.NamingContainer;
Label referenceNo = (Label)Item.FindControl("rptrControlNo");
Label name = (Label)Item.FindControl("rptrRequester");
Label employeeNo = (Label)Item.FindControl("rptrEmployeeNo");
Label entryDate = (Label)Item.FindControl("rptrEntryDate");
Label document = (Label)Item.FindControl("rptrDocu");
Label Approver = (Label)Item.FindControl("rptrApprover");
Label requestStatus = (Label)Item.FindControl("rptrReqStatus");
Label rejectRemarks = (Label)Item.FindControl("rptrRejectRemarks");

hide_rptrControlNo.Text = referenceNo.Text;
hide_rptrStatus.Text = requestStatus.Text;
```

The code above produces the following error message.

> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItem' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater'.

Markup:

```
 <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptrCERFormsMonItems">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1">
                <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanelRepeater" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                    <Triggers></Triggers>
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" ID="btnCERFormsMon_Print" OnClick="btnCERFormsMon_Print_Click" CausesValidation="false" Text="<i class='fa fa-print' aria-hidden='true'></i> PRINT"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </td>
            <td class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="rptrControlNo" Text='<%#Eval("DI_REFERENCENO")%>' Style="text-transform: uppercase" />
            </td>
            <td class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="rptrRequester" Text='<%#Eval("DI_REQUESTEDBY")%>' Style="text-transform: uppercase" />
            </td>
            <td class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="rptrEmployeeNo" Text='<%#Eval("DI_EMPLOYEENO")%>' Style="text-transform: uppercase" />
            </td>
            <td class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="rptrEntryDate" Text='<%#Eval("DI_ENTRYDATE")%>' Style="text-transform: uppercase; float:right;" />
            </td>
            <td class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="rptrDocu" Text='<%#Eval("DI_DOCUMENTTOREQUEST")%>' Style="text-transform: uppercase" />
            </td>
            <td class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="rptrApprover" Text='<%#Eval("DI_APPROVER")%>' Style="text-transform: uppercase" />
            </td>
            <td class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="rptrReqStatus" Text='<%#Eval("DI_REQUESTSTATUS")%>' Style="text-transform: uppercase" />
            </td>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="rptrRejectRemarks" Text='<%#Eval("DI_REJECTREMARKS")%>' Visible="false" />
                <asp:Label runat ="server" ID="rptrTime" Text='<%#Eval("DI_ENTRYTIME")%>' Visible="false" />
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Unfortunately repeater is a method used for displaying and it cant find any item in the datatable when I bind it on my repeater so I have to use the repeaterItem method to cast repeater's obj.

```
 RepeaterItem Item = (RepeaterItem)btnCerFormsMon_Print.NamingContainer;
```